# How to find the min value in a pandas data frame when some values are equal

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame something like this:

```
PatientID       Date 
1               01/01/2011
3               03/03/2012
3               15/01/2015
1               01/01/2011
```

[link to better representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWdex.png)

and I want to find the minimum date per PatientID, this this:

[image]

I am doing the following:

```
min_date = patient_df.groupby("PatientID", as_index=False)["Date"].min()
```

This seems to work but, for `PatientID == 1` for example, it returns a `NaN`. Is this because the date for `PatientID == 1` is the same for all associated rows?

If you compare two values and they are the same then why doesn't it return that value as the minimum as there isn't a value lower?

Help for this newbie would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue described, which version of pandas do you have ?

Comment: Works fine for me as well

Comment: Does it actually fail on _this sample_?  If not, please provide a sample that actually does produce the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also worked fine for me when I tried to reproduce.  However, I thought maybe the problem was that the data type was not captured correctly.

Below is a solution, which creates another column that ensures the proper datetime format.

```
import pandas as pd
patient_df = pd.read_clipboard()
patient_df['proper date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
min_date = patient_df.groupby("PatientID", as_index=False)["proper date"].min()

min_date
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you - I think this was the issue.